# Where to store settings in chrome extension app

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am new to web development. I am writing google chrome extension that connects to some API. I have one page for user's settings with fields like API key, and more stuff that user want's to configure.

My question as a developer where and how should I save this settings, I thought creating a json file that it would be possible to export the file and import settings file.

Should the server save this settings? should I save it on user's machine? any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be better if you allow user to save on their machine, it's safer and your users have to take all responsibility to keep it safe.

You can use [Extension Options](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options) to provide a UI for your users to save their credentials. And in that option page, you should use [chrome.storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) to store the credentials so that whenever user access to option page, their credentials still there. Later on, when you want to use user credentials to send API, just use `chrome.storage API` to query the credential.